# SQL change static connection string if there is no connection

Tags: c#, .net, sql, connection

I have static class, which return connection string like:

```
public static string cString()
{ 
    //(...)

    string connString = String.empty;
    //check if it have to read connString from file or use static connstring
    if(readConnStringFromFile)
        connString = "...";
    else
        connString = "...";

    return connString;
}
```

So now anywhere in application im creating new connection to server like:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (cString.connString))
```

I have 2 databases. If application lose connection to main DB, I'd like to change connectionString into second one. Is it possible (for example in App.xaml.cs) to check connection to database and if it doesnt response change it?
If its possible, how much will it overload application?
I need best method, which wont overload it so much, becouse PC's are quiet weak.

Comment: At what moment possibly you want to switch to different database? If you can decide at the start, then its pretty easy. You try to open connection with first one like `conn.Open()` and close it straightaway if you don't want to reuse it there via `conn.Close()`, if it fails, you fall back to secondary one.

Comment: For example, when I want to show information about product - after click "show" button it's trying to get information about that product from database, so if there is no connection I'd like to switch it.
Problem is that I have a lot of opened connection in application. So best solution for me will be that, if ANY connection connection opened in application return that it can't connect -> switch database. Question is that, is it possible... ?

Comment: Ok. I find out that in App.xaml.cs I created dispatcher, which tick every x second and check : if there is connection to DB1-> use DB1, else use DB2. But i guess this is not really good solution?

Comment: That's not a very neat solution I'd suspect. Try keeping your data access layer separate. And only open/close/manage connections in there using DataContext. Which is basically separation of concern. Your front-end should be independent of what you are doing in database and vice versa.

Comment: Why not just pass string[] back with all possible connections and let individuals calls deal with using alternates.